# How can I wire up a back button in my OSX app

Tags: objective-c, macos, interface-builder

I would like to have the functionality to go back to a previous view or even just a view I specify in my objective-c code. I have created the back button object, connected it to a property in the views interface as well as connecting it to an IBAction. What is the actual command to go back a view though, I have been trying the following

```
-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender{
    [[_window contentView] replaceSubview:currentView with:previousView];
}
```

Is there a way to always go to the previous view rather than having to specify exactly which one to go to?

Does interface builder provide a way to link views together to handle the flow of the application or must it always be done in code?

Comment: i don't fully understand your question

Comment: Basically I just want to make a common back button method that will always go to the previous view a user was on.

Comment: Interface builder does provide application flow through storyboards but it's based (mostly) on view controllers and segues rather than individual views.